# C++ array overloading operator []

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

```
class myClass {
    public:
        int y[2];
        myClass() {
            y[0] = 0;
            y[1] = 0;
        }
        void operator[](int x) {
            //
        }
};

int main() {
    myClass myobj();
    //myobj.y[0] = 1;

    return 0;
}
```

I have the above class myClass with one public member, an integer array of two elements. Now, I need, instead of writing in main `myobj.y[0] = 1;`, to overload operator[] so that, by writing `y[0] = 1;` to do the same action, setting an element of the array to equal something, `1` here for example. I have been struggling on this over an hour, at first I don't know what to declare the operator[], maybe void? And secondly, in any case, I can pass the position of the array to argument x but I don't know how to pass the value, should I overload operator = too?

Comment: You are on the right track. Here's a tutorial: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/subscripting_operator_overloading.htm

Comment: @RSahu +1, better than my answer; you've taught the OP how to fish.

Comment: @Bathsheba, SO is just one of many resources on the web to find answers to such questions. Hope people make use of as many of them as they can.

Comment: really nice example but goes with my problem, being aple to pass the position but not the value ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return a *reference* to the vector element so you can modify it via that reference:

```
int& operator[](std::size_t index) {
    /*ToDo - some bounds checking here?*/
    return y[index];
}
```

will do it. `std::size_t` is appropriate here as it will be correctly sized for your platform.

Comment: And you will access the object in main as myobj[0]=1, not y[0]=1